# Changing colors of the powershell prompt in Windows 10

Tags: command-line, windows-10, powershell, colors

In Windows 10, the powershell prompt has improved with more coloring. Command parameters are now highlighted in a different color, making the experience much nicer.
However, I like to customize the colors of my command prompt to the monokai theme (see https://github.com/ntwb/posh-monokai).

I get the following problem though with the new highlighting in windows 10:

[image: Color problem]

Is there a way to modify those colors?

Comment: `Set-PSReadlineOption -TokenKind Parameter -ForegroundColor Red`

Comment: Indeed, thanks. Could you add it as an answer so I can mark it as answered?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Command line coloring in PowerShell v5 provided by `PSReadline` module. You can change various `PSReadline` module options by `Set-PSReadlineOption` command. In particular, to change parameter token color you need following command:

```
Set-PSReadlineOption -TokenKind Parameter -ForegroundColor Red
```